# Does ECharts export the type for click events?

Tags: javascript, typescript, echarts

Within [Apache ECharts we can received click events](https://apache.github.io/echarts-handbook/en/concepts/event/) like this?

```
myChart.on('click', function(params) {
  // Print name in console
  console.log(params.name);
});
```

And the documentation also mentions that the type for mouse events is `EventParams` however I don't see this exported in the source?

Does anyone know whether ECharts exposes a type for click events?

Comment: https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/19297

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't do this the trick?

```
import { ECElementEvent, ... } from 'echarts';
myChart.on('click', function(event: ECElementEvent) {
  /* .. */
});
```

Comment: that looked promising.  I tried it out and it's missing some of the properties that are contained on the event like `event.value`.  Welcome to SO!!